# Deriving a graph of current through secondary given graph of voltage across primary

Tags: voltage, current, transformer

I am a bit confused after a question from my physics textbook. We are currently going through some basics of electromagnetism, one of the topics being the workings of transformers. I figured the question may be more suited for here.

The question of concern is about interpreting a graph of the voltage across the primary of the transformer to conclude a graph of the current through the secondary. The graph we derive for the current only has to be a rough guess i.e. the correct shape. I should mention that it is an ideal transformer we are dealing with. We are given the following function for the primary voltage over time.

[image]

### My Attempt

Start with the transformer equation.

\$\frac{I_s}{I_p}=\frac{n_p}{n_s}\$

Where \$n\$ is number of coil turns. The above equation implies that our secondary current is proportional to our primary current by a factor of \$\frac{n_p}{n_s}\$. So the graph of secondary current against time should look similar to the primary current against time. Since the primary coil is an inductor we can say that \$V=L\frac{dI}{dt}\$ and so the graph of primary current against time will be proportional to the integral of \$V_p\$ w.r.t time. So we can infer that roughly our primary current should be quadratic from \$t\in[0,1]\$, linear for \$t\in[1,4]\$ and quadratic again for \$t\in [4,7]\$. \$I_s\$ will be proportional to this graph by \$\frac{n_p}{n_s}\$ hence it will look similar on each interval (i.e. Quadratic, linear, quadratic).

### Solution

The correct solution given by the textbook was the following graph with the following explanation (Note that \$S_1\$ is the primary coil and \$S_2\$ is the secondary coil).

[image]

So from their graph it seems that \$I_s\$ is proportional to \$-\frac{dV_p}{dt}\$ but I can't understand how to derive this mathematically nor does it make sense to me intuitively when considering the inductor equation.

Comment: Err, strange. Does it assume infinite magnetizing inductance? Is any load on the secondary given?

Comment: In an **ideal** transformer (so no core saturation or winding resistance), secondary voltage = primary voltage x turns_ratio (even for DC excitation, but that's 'ideal' for you!). Without knowing the load on the secondary, you cannot infer the secondary current from the secondary voltage. The question is unanswerable, and their solution is plain wrong. What text book is this????? Your answer for Ip is correct, for Is it depends on the load, is correct for a resistive load.

Comment: @winny It hasn't mentioned anything about either of those two conditions. We haven't covered magnetizing inductance so I doubt it would assume infinite without stating so. If it makes their solution correct, you could assume a load on the secondary side but again nothing else was given in the question other than to derive a graph of current in the secondary.

Comment: @Neil_UK Interesting. This textbook is definetly questionable. My school has given us another textbook from the same company for mathematics and it seems to be riddled with errors in some parts (Hence why I was tentative about the solutions in the physics textbook).